# Making simple Nested List where sublist appear to side of the main list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a Simple Nested List which will be some what similar to this Image.In the Image Main list is on Left and if there's any sublist it will appear on the right on mouse over.[image: sample look]
  the Link to what I'm trying looks like [-sample at jsfiddle you can see](http://jsfiddle.net/rainbow99984/GDNe8/1/)  Here the Problem I'm facing is
Q1 The Sublist is not easy navigable if you hover from list first to second and to third the whole list will disappear. behavior is not consistent may be because of design.

Q2. In My main page where I have to integrate it,
 it keeps Pushing down all the element below it How can i handle it.

Q3. Right now the list is displayed like normal nested list, any help on making/showing side by side as in attached Image
for reference I'm putting the codes here too.

```
<ul id="ScatList" style="list-style: none inside;cursor: pointer;position: relative;margin: 0px;height:10px;">
  <li><span><em>List</em></span>
      <ul id="liststart" style="display: none;position:absolute;padding:2px 2px 10px 2px;top:20px;left:190px;text-align:justify" class="search-menu">
        <li> <a>First</a>
            <ul >
                <li><a>1.1</a></li>
                <li><a>1.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> Second
            <ul >
                <li><a>2.1</a></li>
                <li>2.2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> Third
            <ul >
                <li>3.1</li>
                <li>3.2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**Javscript**:

```
jQuery('#ScatList').hover(function() {
    jQuery('#liststart').show(400);
}, function() {
    jQuery('#liststart').hide();
});
jQuery('#liststart >li').hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('ul').show(400);
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).find('ul').hide();
});
jQuery('#liststart >li> ul').hide();
```

Comment: Please someone format it the first list appear inline I tried to format it to put as code but failed.

Comment: In case you're not doing this to learn and you just need something that will work, there's a jquery plugin : http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/

Comment: the thing with `Superfish` is that it should just be used as an enhancement to an **already working** menu

Comment: @clairesuzy Thanks for edit how you do it i tried putting in in **`**(tick) but failed  :) I'm doing for the work, and Possibly not looking to work with the plug-in,not any specific reason but will if not possible otherwise, the image i have attached is the working version without plugin that i know.

Comment: @JohnP Superfish is also very good exactly with the looks that i have attached but i'll go with the @Marcus Ekwall suggested code as My need is simple enough. Thanks.

Comment: @clairesuzy definitely. Superfish actually makes you do it in any case since the markup is semantic

Comment: @rain, code has to be indented 4 spaces, but best just to type the code with normal indents the select it all and use the `{}` button to indent it the required extra spaces after that @JohnP yes it's very good, but I see lots who expect SF to make it align rather just enhance the effect ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find my [minimalistic navigation plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/XR4Wt/) useful for this. You're free to use the code and change it to your own liking.

Comment: Thanks Man Its Good, I was looking for Similar structure. Thanks again. :)

Comment: hi,I'm facing some problem the fiddle link of yours I have the same css but it is not working in IE7,8 both the sub-menu is always remain hidden any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: @rain, I haven't tested it in pre-IE9. Making it pre-IE9 compatible isn't something I will do because it's unproductive. If you need it to work in IE7/8 you'd have to make the necessary changes/fixes yourself. If you ask me, people and companies need to learn to upgrade :-)

Comment: thanks, got it, something to do with the doctype. i put it and its working :)

Comment: Hi, once again i'm having problem on IE with quirks mode due to some reason i can not change it can you please have a look on the modified link http://jsfiddle.net/rainbow99984/8qu4d/1/ 
it is working fine in firefox, chrome but not in IE if change the doctype then it is working but i'm not permitted to change the doctype. any reason or fix as why the nested list is not appearing.
thanks again.